# Zero condition for bounded operators on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I found in a math textbook this exercise: show that, if *A* is a linear bounded operator on a complex hilbert space *H* and *<x|Ax> = $0$* for every *x* in *H*, then *A= $0$*. Why the operator is required to be bounded? An hint  is specified in the textbook: use the expression *<x+cy|A(x+cy)> = $0$*, valid for every *x,y* in *H* and complex number *c*. Considering the suggestion:

*<x+cy|A(x+cy)>=<x|Ax>+$|c|^2$<y|Ay>+$c^*$<y|Ax>+$c$<x|Ay>= $c^*$<y|Ax>+$c$<x|Ay>=$0$*

and, using *c=1*, *<y|Ax>=-<x|Ay>*, using *c=i*, *<y|Ax>=<x|Ay>* for every x,y in *H*. So it must be *<y|Ax>=$0$* for every x,y in *H*, which means *A=$0$*. The problem is I didn't use the boundedness of the operator and, because of that, I'm not sure the proof is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Boundeness is not required. This result is purely algebraic.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was having trouble because I've often found this one in various notes, but I've never understood why they require boundedness.